# Can i send sms using twilio as though coming from my verizon number

Tags: sms, twilio

Can user send sms from my app to friends using twilio . End user should get sms from the user, rather than a twilio assigned number. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately no.  Currently Twilio only allows you to use a Twilio phone number as the sender ID when sending text messages.

Check out this FAQ:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app

Hope that helps.